# Port testing with telnet - Close session cleanly

Tags: windows, telnet

I use telnet   to test services running very frequently. At times I find that if the service is running and the telnet session opens, I cannot close the session in a clean way. I have to close the command prompt window.

I have tried typing CTRL + C, quit, exit, bye

Some sessions just do not respond and have to close the prompt window. Is there a way to always send a "close session" from the prompt without closing the window?

Comment: Have you given any thoughts as opposed to telnet, using powershell test-connection? It would be a tad bit cleaner and maybe give you more functionality? Give logs in csv format of what you're doing? Just a thought.

Comment: I will check that out, thank you for the suggestion. I use windows and Linux and switch between telnet and netstat -an, but I will check out test-connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> then type `quit`. This will do the trick.

Comment: Oh thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The CTRL-character is different from one national keyboard-layout to the other. On my Danish laptop-keyboard, it is CTRL + ¨ and then "quit" + Enter.